# Log in form and store username/passwords in a file in aray structure

Tags: vb.net, authentication

Currently my code is:

```
Public Structure
   Dim Username as String
   Dim Password as String


Dim Read() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Passwords.txt")
        Dim PassArray(Read.Length - 1) As Account

        For i = 0 To PassArray.Length - 1
            Dim line() = Split(Read(i), ","c)
            PassArray(i).Username = line(0)
            PassArray(i).password = line(1)
        Next

        If PassArray(0).Username = txtUsername.Text Then
            If PassArray(1).password = txtPassword.Text Then
                Form1.Show()

            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Wrong Username or Password!")
        End If
```

I get an 'index outside the bounds of the array at PassArray(i).password = line(1)

I think i may have structured this wrong

the test file looks like:

```
Username
Password
```

Comment: Well, I see that you're using two arrays on that line?  Have you actually looked at the two of them to see which one the index is out of range for?  Have you looked to see what the range is and why it's not what you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, If you doesn't work, let me know and i will do my best to help you out :)

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

Public Structure info
    Dim Username As String
    Dim Password As String
End Structure

Dim details As info

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If TextBox1.Text = details.Username And TextBox2.Text = details.Password Then
        MessageBox.Show("Correct!")
        Form2.Show()
        Me.hide()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("wrong")
        Textbox1.Clear()
        Textbox2.Clear()
    End If
End Sub

    Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim FILE = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Passwords.txt")
    Dim myArray As String() = FILE
    details.Username = myArray(0)
    details.Password = myArray(1)
End Sub
End Class
```

You don't have to use the Structure, but I included it because it was a part of your question.
 Happy Coding!

Comment: The logic works, but it doesnt let me into my main program, i edited the main post with an update on what the Passwords.txt actually was :)

Comment: ok, since you have copied the password.txt file to your program, in solution explorer click on the password test file and press F4, set it to `always Copy`. And Also i am doing this from a button click event, make sure you have it on the same or else the code will need to be edited. And when you mean it doesn't let you into your main program, i put `Form2.show()` maybe you have to change it to `Form1.Show()` most of the t'me form1 is default so i guessed form2 would be next.

Comment: i dont see an "Always copy" in the "Password.txt properties?

Comment: The only difference i see from your code to mine is yours has "public sub form1_Load, where mine is private sub??

Comment: Hey mate, post all of your code and ill take a look for you